# Cutting and defraying metal railing cable

Tags: tools, cutting, railing

I am new to installing railing metal cable. One problem that I encountered is that, when I cut the cable with a grinder, it leaves the end slightly wider than the cable and often frayed threads so that it won't fit inside the ferrule of the swivel end, which is barely wide enough to fit the nominal width of the cable. I am using the `Atlantis` railing system.

I tried cutting it with electric cutoff pliers but they were not strong enough so I resorted to a grinder. Is there a tool, or a method of cutting, that will neatly cut the cable and then twist or splice any frayed threads so that it fits nicely into the ferrule?

Comment: did you ask the manufacturer? ... have you tried putting the ferrule on the cable and then cutting the cable?

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong tool. You need a cable cutters. These cutters are constructed so they "hold" the strands together while they cut through the cable. See picture below.

[image]

In a pinch, you can put a small hose clamp around the wire, tighten the heck out of it and then use  tool with a cutoff wheel or your grinder. Think about getting the proper tool though. It will make your job easier since you've got a lot of cutting to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could get extra ferrules, either of the actual part that's used in this system or just a simple hardware store ferrule for the same size of wire rope. Slide the ferrule onto the wire rope and cut through both the ferrule and the rope (or cut right at the end face of the ferrule). The ferrule collar will prevent the wire rope from fraying at the cut.

It might also work to rotate the wire rope while cutting it. Work so that the cutting disc acts to push the strands toward the core of the rope rather than pulling them away from it.

Comment: It's a proprietary ferrule, tapered on one end